# Eclipse showing :- An internal error occurred during: "Searching for markers". GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: eclipse, memory, junit, build, initialization

I am not able to build Java project in eclipse. It shows error message as below:

[image: eclipse error message.]

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail. What version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks greg-449 for your response. I am using eclipse Mars. I was able to resolve this issue by increasing memory in eclipse.ini file.